Is there a good way to avoid Spring AI responses that use a Vector Store to stop talking about Context?
I am noticing that when I add a vector store I am constantly getting responses like

"Sadly, it seems the context doesn't have any secret blueprints or insider gossip about your specific Z-Wave network."

I get why it says this but it seems to happen a lot and always seems off. Short of an advisor that resubmits and says remove references to context, is there a way to configure the OpenAI to not talk about the context? Is there a way StringTemplate or something I can use?

Can you [edit] to share what your prompts look like? I would posit that the word “context” is something that appears somewhere in your prompt; if so, it may be as easy as re-architecting said prompt to avoid the use of the term “context” or to add to the prompt you already have to try to set a guardrail on the output you get.

i think you can add system prompt that says something like don't tell uses anything about vector store or anything if you don't find an answer than simply say i don't lnow answer.
